# Play reverse routing - .unique, different packages

Tags: playframework, routes

In the example twirl template ([scalacomet.scala.html, line 18](https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-streaming-example/blob/4d3e2712e942cc950352aab2f432290f95279922/app/views/scalacomet.scala.html#L18)) reverse routing is done with the suffix `.unique` (see below). This extends the URL with a unique param - is there any documentation about that?

`@routes.ScalaCometController.streamClock.unique`

Is it possible to do reverse routing from a Scala call not located in package controllers?

```
routes:  GET  /hallo    com.example.controllers.App.hallo()
```

`@routes.com.example.controllers.App.hallo` seems not to work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for reverse routes is [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaRouting#Reverse-routing).

The type returned by `routes.ScalaCometController.streamClock` is an [`play.api.mvc.Call`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/play/api/mvc/Call.html). The documentation for `unique` is in the superclass [`play.mvc.Call`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/java/play/mvc/Call.html#unique--).

> `public Call unique()`
>
> Append a unique identifier to the URL.
>
> Returns: a copy if this call with a unique identifier to this url

Here's the explanation in the docs of how reverse routes are generated for classes in each package.

> Note: There is a routes subpackage for each controller package. So the action controllers.Application.hello can be reversed via controllers.routes.Application.hello (as long as there is no other route before it in the routes file that happens to match the generated path).

In your example that would be `@com.example.controllers.routes.App.hallo`.